# Swift: Returning an In-Out function

Tags: swift, swift-playground

How do I write a function that returns another function that takes an in-out parameter?

I want to write the function `makeIncrementor` that returns an `incrementor` function. This `incrementor` function takes one In-Out parameter and increments it by a certain amount (it doesn't return anything). Here's my code:

```
func makeIncrementor(amount:Int) -> Int->Void {
    func incrementor(inout variable:Int) -> Void {
        variable += amount;
    }
    return incrementor;
}

var x = 1;
var inc = makeIncrementor(2);
inc(&x)
//x should now contain 3
```

However, Xcode gives the following error:

```
<REPL>:9:12: error: 'Int' is not a subtype of 'inout Int'
    return incrementor;
           ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I assume you mean `var inc = makeIncrementor(2)`?

Answer (score 1):

The argument list for the function that is being returned should be wrapped in parens, and should include `inout` before the argument that you want to modify, e.g.

*(to see it more clearly, wrap the return value of `makeIncrementor` in parens as well)*

```
func makeIncrementor(amount:Int) -> ((inout Int) -> Void) {
    func incrementor(inout variable:Int) -> Void {
        variable += amount;
    }
    return incrementor;
}
```

Comment: Now I'm getting the following error:
`Playground execution failed: error: error: Couldn't lookup symbols:
  __TMdRSi`

Answer (score 1):

You are returning the `incrementor` function, which has the type `(inout Int) -> ()` while you are declaring your `makeIncrementor` function returns the type `Int -> ()`

This mismatch is the reason for your error and changing

```
func makeIncrementor(amount:Int) -> Int-> ()
```

to

```
func makeIncrementor(amount : Int) -> (inout Int) -> ()
```

Is the correct fix. However if you currently try to run that code in a playground it will crash!

I have successfully run the following code in both OSX and iOS Xcode projects so there are clearly still some stability issues with playgrounds in Xcode.

```
func makeIncrementor(amount : Int) -> (inout Int) -> () {
    func incrementor(inout variable:Int) {
        variable += amount
    }
    return incrementor
}

var incByTwo = makeIncrementor(2)
var incByThree = makeIncrementor(3)    

var a = 5

println(a) // 5

incByTwo(&a)
println(a) // 7


incByThree(&a)
println(a) // 10
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the return type to:

```
func makeIncrementor(amount: Int) -> inout Int -> Void {
    // ...
}
```

Then the error goes away but my Xcode crashes.